# Unable to add HTML.BeginForm inside ASP.NET WebGrid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, webgrid, html.beginform

I have the following code inside my asp.net MVC-4 razor view:-

```
gridcolumns.Add(new WebGridColumn()
    {
        CanSort = false,
        Format =
         (item) =>
         {
             var banner = item.Value as Sales.Models.DeleteAllRequest;
             if (!banner.Approved)
             {
                 return Html.ActionLink("Approve", "DeleteRequestDeleteAll", "Customer", new { customerid = banner.CustomerID, requestid = banner.ID },
new AjaxOptions
{
    Confirm = "Are You sure You want to delete (" + banner.CustomerName.ToString() + ")",
    OnSuccess = "deletionconfirmation",
    OnFailure = "deletionerror"
});
             }
             return "";

         }

    });
```

The above code will add `<a>` link inside the ASP.NET web grid column. but since i am doing a Delete action so i should be sending Post request instead of Get request. so i am not sure how i can use `Html.BeginForm` instead of `Html.ActionLink` inside my above code?

Thanks

Comment: You can't do DELETE in an HTML form anyways. Just GET and POST. You can use DELETE or whatever verb you want if you use AJAX or similar techniques.

Comment: @mason yes if we want to follow the web standards, but most of the people will perform a delete by sending Post request to the server..